# Why is it faster to zip a million 1KB files, transfer them, and unzip them, than to directly transfer those same files?

Tags: file-transfer, zip

This is not just for local drive transfers. I've even noticed that when pushing or pulling files to servers, or simply uploading to a service like Google Drive, it is usually significantly faster to zip up many small files (even using just the "store" ZIP option), transfer them, and then unzip them.

If this is the case, why don't most services (like rsync, Windows/macOS file transfer, etc.) that do this automatically? For example, if the user is trying to transfer more than 1000x files of very small size, automatically "zip up" the files to a temporary location, transfer them, and then unzip them? Or maybe do this "on the fly" so that it doesn't take up unnecessary disk space?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're surprised that a network transfer of 1 million small files is slow?

Comment: Overheads and latency. The reading of files on one side and then writing of on the other will be the same in either case, but the network introduces latency for *every* file request which says "I'm sending you a file" "Cool brah, send it" "Here it is..." The time cost to zip up all the files in one single file is a far lower than the collective network latency. squillmans answer is pretty much bang on. Both sides *have* to read all the files anyway, so if they can compress or absorb all the time spent talking to each other then it will be faster.

Comment: Actually transferring many small files is not necessarily always slower than transferring a single zipped file. It can be as fast (or possibly faster in some cases) if the transfers are parallelized. I am not aware of transfer protocols with built-in parallelization, but at least some front end tools do that, for instance Filezilla, which can run up to 10 simultaneous transfer tasks. While a task is talking to the remote machine (overheads etc...) another task is effectively transferring data, so that the whole bandwidth is used.

Comment: @Mokubai with reading/writing multiple small files, the file system introduces the overheads too (need to read/write the directory for each file). If you just copy 1 million files 1 KB each on the disk, within the same computer, without network transfer, it will be significantly slower than copying a single 1 GB file. This is particularly visible with slow media like USB drives.

Comment: @raj yes, but the overhead there is orders of magnitude lower than the latency involved in network communications. The effect is similar, but when the speed of doing it locally is 10, 100, 1000 or even 10000 times faster then the net difference will end up showing more and more in the end copy speed. Networking is slower than any modern CPU in doing cache lookups, memory copies, compression and other events that are held entirely within a local system. A 1millisecond network latency is far slower than taking 100nano seconds to compress a 1kb file and adding it to an archive buffer in memory.

Comment: @Mokubai I guess my question then is, why aren't *all* file transfers automatically "zipped" so that it's akin to transferring one very large file, to reduce any latency? This might not help much when transferring big files, but I can see a strong argument for this to be done for smaller files

Comment: @SkeletonBow probably because that would break the file based nature of a network file system and bloat the code up. You wouldn't want to do it for every file, as doing it for a 200GB uncompressible video file would be a waste of time and CPU cycles. So *when* do you do it? The answer to that is an impossible to quantify because there are too many networks with different speeds and latencies, to many fast and slow CPUs, HDDs and SSDs that all affect the "sweet spot" of when to do this kind of intelligent compression. Better to leave the "intelligent" side to a human who knows the hardware.

Comment: Also it would require the various tools people use for file management such as Explorer, which are entirely separate from the network stack and network filesystem drivers, to have intimate knowledge of the network filesystem capabilities. It would require the file copying program to pass over the entire list of files at once and say "you deal with that" which shifts programming effort and complexity and you end up with two sets of code doing vaguely similar things instead of having clear delineation of tasks and purpose. It's better to use well defined tools to deal with edge cases like this.

Comment: @SkeletonBow As Squillman mentioned, this is a question for the developers. IMO there's no need to implement that within the protocols themselves, as it can be done in the tools that use the protocols (e.g. making a tarball that is piped to a ssh command). Note that packing the files does make sense only in a client/server scheme (this excludes  transfers between disks mounted on a single computer).

Answer (score 2):

With each file individually, the overhead of a separate network connection is involved for all files which adds a considerable amount to the overall time it takes.  If the connections are encrypted, even moreso.

With a single zip file, only a single file gets transferred with only that network overhead.  That is *significantly* faster as the number of files increases.

Why it's not implemented isn't really something we can answer, that's a developer / vendor question.  One thing could be that it's not guaranteed that the same zip technology is available on the remote side.

Comment: Packing the files could be implemented within the transfer protocol, and even without the need of a temporary file.

Comment: Sure it could.  With existing versions of the protocols, though, there is no option for that.  It would be an excellent feature to add, IMHO. Updates to existing transfer protocols could implement this, doing the packing internally.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `rsync` is maybe working (more or less) like that.

Comment: Could be, I'm not sure either

Comment: Another (obvious) reason why a zipped transfer can be faster is the compression : the size compressed data can be much smaller in some cases.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the predominant explanation here.  Transferring a million compressed files is going to suffer from the same network overhead from a relative perspective.  The overall transfer time might be shorter because of the compression but the same effect would be encountered regarding numbers of files.

Comment: @PierU Even without any sort of compression, a zipped transfer seems to be significantly faster than a direct transfer

Comment: @squillman I agree that it would be an excellent feature. It would be such an excellent feature to implement such a simple idea that my question is why no one has ever done this before